# How do I use SSH in a Jenkins pipeline?

Tags: node.js, git, jenkins, ssh, jenkins-pipeline

I have some Jenkins jobs defined using a Jenkins Pipeline Model Definition, which builds NPM projects. I use Docker containers to build these projects (using a common image with
just Node.js + npm + yarn).

The results of the builds are contained in the `dist/` folder that I zipped using a `zip` pipeline command.

I want to copy this ZIP file to another server using SSH/SCP (with private key authentication). My private key is added to the Jenkins environment (credentials manager), but when I use Docker containers, an SSH connection cannot be established.

I tried to add `agent { label 'master' }` to use the master Jenkins node for file transfer, but it seems to create a clean workspace with new Git fetch, and without my built files.

After I tried the SSH Agent Plugin, I have this output:

```
Identity added: /srv/jenkins3/workspace/myjob-TFD@tmp/private_key_370451445598243031.key (rsa w/o comment)
[ssh-agent] Started.
[myjob-TFD] Running shell script
+ scp -r dist test@myremotehost:/var/www/xxx
$ docker exec bfda17664965b14281eef8670b34f83e0ff60218b04cfa56ba3c0ab23d94d035 env SSH_AGENT_PID=1424 SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/ssh-k658r0O76Yqb/agent.1419 ssh-agent -k
unset SSH_AUTH_SOCK;
unset SSH_AGENT_PID;
echo Agent pid 1424 killed;
[ssh-agent] Stopped.
Host key verification failed.
lost connection
```

How do I add a remote host as authorized?

Comment: I have the same issue, the sshagent plugin does not workin in a container

Comment: use  withCredentials and delete sshAgent plugin ```withCredentials([sshUserPrivateKey(credentialsId: 'ssh-credentials-id', keyFileVariable: 'keyfile')]) {
              sh "mkdir -p ~/.ssh && cp ${keyfile} ~/.ssh/id_rsa" other_stuff}```

Comment: backing up with @SZMER said: [sshagent plugin broken on Windows 10 version 1803](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-51968?focusedCommentId=381529&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-381529)

Answer (score 35):

I had a similar issue. I did not use the label 'master', and I identified that the file transfer works across slaves when I do it like this:

Step 1 - create SSH keys in a remote host server, include the key to authorized_keys

Step 2 - Create credential using SSH keys in Jenkins, use the private key from the remote host

Use the [SSH agent plugin](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/ssh-agent/):

```
stage ('Deploy') {
    steps{
        sshagent(credentials : ['use-the-id-from-credential-generated-by-jenkins']) {
            sh 'ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no user@hostname.com uptime'
            sh 'ssh -v user@hostname.com'
            sh 'scp ./source/filename user@hostname.com:/remotehost/target'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't disable StrictHostKeyChecking. This is terribly insecure, especially in a CI/CD environment.

Comment: @LieRyan is right. You can easily get rid of this warning if you login to you Jenkins via SSH and execute `ssh-keyscan -H 192.168.1.162 >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts`. Of course you have to adjust the command to your needs.

Comment: @Murolack Still this is not a good solution. You will trust any host regardless and one more line will added at every run. Much better to create known_hosts manually once.

Comment: @sekrett my solution is to create the know_hosts file manually or at least add the new host to the already existing file. You execute this command on the server to add this one server you want to connect to.

Answer (score 9):

Use the SSH agent plugin:

- *[SSH Agent Plugin](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/ssh-agent/)*
- *[SSH Agent Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/SSH+Agent+Plugin)*

When using this plugin you can use the global credentials.

Comment: I tried the plugin you specified and updated question consequently.

Comment: How to use credentials from SSH plugin in pipeline script?

Answer (score 2):

To add a remote host to known hosts and hopefully cope with your error try to manually ssh from the Jenkins host to the target host as the Jenkins user.

Get on the host where Jenkins is installed. Type

```
sudo su jenkins
```

Now use ssh or scp like

```
ssh username@server
```

You should be prompted like this:

> The authenticity of host 'server (ip)' can't be established.
>   ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:some-weird-string.
>   Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?

Type yes. The server will be permanently added as a known host. Don't even bother passing a password, just <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> and try running a Jenkins job.

Comment: why down vote? It is a correct answer to updated question.

Answer (score 1):

Like @haschibaschi recommends, I also use the ssh-agent plugin. I have a need to use my personal UID credentials on the remote machine, because it doesn't have any UID Jenkins account. The code looks like this (using, for example, my personal UID="myuid" and remote server hostname="non_jenkins_svr":

```
sshagent(['e4fbd939-914a-41ed-92d9-8eededfb9243']) {
    // 'myuid@' required for scp (this is from UID jenkins to UID myuid)
    sh "scp $WORKSPACE/example.txt myuid@non_jenkins_svr:${dest_dir}"
}
```

The ID e4fbd939-914a-41ed-92d9-8eededfb9243 was generated by the Jenkins credentials manager after I created a global domain credentials entry.

After creating the credentials entry, the ID is found under the "ID" column on the credentials page. When creating the entry, I selected type 'SSH Username with private key' ('Kind' field), and copied the RSA private key I had created for this purpose under the myuid account on host `non_jenkins_svr` without a passphrase.